# Not allowed to call release on NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I have a string that I generate with JSON data from an URL

```
  NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This code is inside viewDidLoad method. I want to release the string before I exit the method to avoid any memory leak, and I do this according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15150685/ios-release-for-nsstring-is-not-working-as-expected).

```
 [strResult release];
```

However, xCode does not allow me by giving error: ARC forbids explicit send message of 'release'.

Anybody knows why? I tried to google it but no luck. I am new to iOS programming, and I have tried to google it before I asked. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this question was Googled before being posted...

Comment: See also [ARC and releasing object created in method](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18727445) and [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: I did google it. But I did not find anything that help me understand it. I tried :)

Comment: ARC codes the release for you.  This is the whole point of ARC.

Answer (score 0):

ARC automatically adds the methods to deallocate objects, at compile time, for you.